# Microsoft Azure: No Connectivity after IP Change

Tags: azure, networking, connectivity

I have a web development machine on Azure, this morning it got slow, stopped responding. I tried restarting apache and sql, i rebooted the machine, nothing. I used the restart in azure a couple of times to no avail. I then used the azure shut down, and after a long time of starting back up, with a new IP, still NO connectivity. Wont even respond to a ping. I have my endpoints defined, I am (trying to) access it via the new IP address and nothing. Is it possible that the machine is not updating its IP address? I never specifically set it static. Is there any other sort of recovery access like the ajax lish access with Linode? Please, any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Josh, you may have some success by utilising the VM extensions to allow you to reset admin access. You don't say if you're using Windows or Linux (I take it Linux?)  Either way you have options: [Linux](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-vmaccess-reset-password-or-ssh/) or [Windows](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-reset-password/). HTH.

Comment: Although there was no indication from Microsoft Status, this appeared to be some sort of connectivity or networking issue on Azure. A bit disturbing considering it lasted nearly 4 hours. Back in business, moving development to Linode! I appreciate the response, yes I'm using Linux.